# Unity - The game scene does not change in the executable file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, menu, mainmenu

Actually, I am having a problem with the game I am creating. I have saved as standalone file with all the scenes open in the "build settings", but when I open the executable file the play button does not work in the main menu to start the game. Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CS_MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void PlayButton() 
    {

        SceneManager.LoadScene("Level 1");
        Debug.Log("Game open");
    }


    void LevelButton()
      {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Level 2");
      }

     void CreditButton()
       {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Credits");
       }


    public void ExitButton()
      {
        Application.Quit();
        Debug.Log("Game closed");

      }

    //public void QuitButton()
    //{
      //  Application.Quit();
        //Debug.Log("Game closed");
    }
```

Comment: Is the button hooked up to the `onClick`, is the scene name typed exactly as it appears in the scene? It is case-sensitive. Does this work in engine and only not work in build?

Comment: Yes. It is hooked up onClick and the name of the scene is exactly as the scene and it works in engine, but not in build.

Comment: Try remaking the buttons. I see in the duplicate thread your rect transforms are almost inverted. Meaning you dragged on vertices of the button quad and dragged a corner to the opposite point of the rect and overlapped the other vertices.

Comment: @TEEBQNE https://imgur.com/UwM4DUC Image here.

Comment: @TEEBQNE Can you help me to solve the problem you are mentioning, please? I think that is the actual barrier causing this problem. I have done the button again and still does not work in build, but works in game scene..

Comment: See in [this image you posted before](https://m.imgur.com/a/DCxJ6m7) how there is a red cross through the box? Remake that entire UI and everything chilled to it. I believe that is your issue.

Comment: @TEEBQNE i have done the UI again and does not work in build, but works in game scene. The same happens if I create a new project.

Comment: @TEEBQNE The play button works now. It was very confusing. The main menu scene and the other scenes to load from the buttons did not have the "Event System". Now all the buttons work in games scene and in build. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Awesome glad you were able to figure it out!